# Unable to call web3.eth.accounts.create() without remote debugger on react native app

Tags: react-native, ethereum, web3js

I am building an android wallet using react-native and trying to create an account using `web3.eth.accounts.create()` . This works with react-native remote debugger enabled. However, when I work the same code with the debugger off, it stops working.

this is my package.json

```
"cryptico": "^1.0.2",
"native-base": "2.8.0",
"node-libs-browser": "2.1.0",
"react": "16.3.1",
"react-native": "0.55.4",
"react-native-firebase": "^5.2.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.12",
"react-native-scripts": "1.14.0",
"react-navigation": "^3.0.9",
"socket.io-client": "2.0.4",
"web3": "1.0.0-beta.34"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by using ethers.js to create new ethereum wallet.

```
// this is specifically for react-native
import 'ethers/dist/shims';
import {ethers} from 'ethers';
// to create a ethereum wallet
let randomWallet = ethers.Wallet.createRandom();
```

Web3.js is really troublesome for react-native
read more here: 
https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/cookbook-react.html#

this is a guide specifically designed for react-native

Answer (score 1):

I've had problems using web3 inside React Native myself, so I switched to [ethers.js](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/) .
It was working better inside RN and its gives you pretty much everything you will need.

Comment: is it possible to create accounts using ethers.js while using web3 for everything else?

Comment: It is possible. Check out their documentation @ https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/getting-started.html .

Comment: I tried using ethers.Wallet.createRandom() but that also only works with the debugger on

Comment: @PranavSinghal Replying you here, to be honest its been almost a year since I've used ethers with RN and at that time they didn't have shims if I remember correctly.
Glad you made it work!